# Android send HTTP Post in onDestroy

Tags: java, android

So for my app I just need a simple way of syncing data to a server. I do not need to worry about any response (at least for now). I thought it would be as simple as just starting a service from the onDestroy of my main activity but for some reason the service is never being created. Is it not possible to make new services from the onDestroy with intent extras? From what I've been able to debug, the variables are never being put into the bundle. Below is my code for my onDestroy().

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustomService.class);
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    extras.putString(Variables.REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY, apiGateway.getTokens().getRefreshToken());
    extras.putString(Variables.ID_TOKEN_KEY, apiGateway.getTokens().getIdToken());
    try {
        extras.putString(RequestFields.CustomObject, new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(CustomObject.asMap()));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    startService(intent);
```

I can't just make the blind request like I would like to (without a service since it seems like overkill) since obviously you can't make network requests on the main UI thread. Wondering if there's a better way of doing such a blind request without even using a service thus bypassing my problem right now with not being able to start it in the first place.

Comment: You could use the `java.util.concurrent` API if you need an alternative solution.

Comment: BTW the onDestroy javadoc says "Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here". I think it could happen that onDestroy is never called.

Comment: @Hawk thanks for that info. I switched to onPause() using a separate thread for my service and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the java.util.concurrent API if you need an alternative solution. The Executors are quite handy and easy to use.

BTW the [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy()) javadoc says:

> Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here". I think it could happen that onDestroy is never called.

But also take care in onPause:

> When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, **so be sure to not do anything lengthy here.**
>
> This callback is mostly used for saving any persistent state the activity is editing, to present a "edit in place" model to the user and making sure nothing is lost if there are not enough resources to start the new activity without first killing this one. This is also a good place to stop things that consume a noticeable amount of CPU in order to make the switch to the next activity as fast as possible. ([JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPause()))

The real question is: Do you need to sync data to server EVERY time "the user no longer actively interacts with the activity, but it is still visible on screen"[[2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onPause())]? onPause should be used to save the "UI fields state". It depends on your use case, maybe a better option is to sync every 5 mins, but I am not sure from the top of my head how to manage turning off the service.